# Php mysql echo results with common column

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to php and mysql.
I have the following table:

```
NAME                 BOOKING
HERR blabla          F915863
FRAU Kblhdahdla      F915863
FRAU lksfdhdsf       F915863
FRAU jkhdasjkddsf    F926173
HERR bjfasbjkfd      F788135
FRAU jkbashhfsa      F788135
```

I want to echo in html or even create another table where I join the names of the same booking into one column Names, like this:

```
NAMES                                            BOOKING
HERR blabla, FRAU Kblhdahdla, FRAU lksfdhdsf     F915863
FRAU jkhdasjkddsf                                F926173
HERR bjfasbjkfd,FRAU jkbashhfsa                  F788135
```

I couldnt find anything like this, probably not searching with the right words.

Comment: `"Select NAME from <table name> GROUP BY BOOKING"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can specify the separator in the GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(NAME SEPARATOR  ', ')
FROM my_table
GROUP BY BOOKING;
```

Comment: Thats exactly what  needed!! Thank you very much!

Comment: You can modify it, so you get the Column names - SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(NAME SEPARATOR  ', ') AS NAMES, BOOKING
FROM my_table
GROUP BY BOOKING;